# Why is grep not only printing lines that end with a period?

Tags: grep, regular-expression

I have a file

```
$cat File
A data file which contains a number of lines .
Most lines start with an upper case letter.
however some start with a lower case letter.
1 or 2 may start with a digit.

They should end with a full stop (period).
but not all do!
This line   has a combination of spaces and  tabs and ends with a space
3 lines are empty

You may want to verify the number of empty lines in this file.

There are some lines which only contain digits and white spaces, like the next 2.
1 2 3   4 5 6
```

No I want to use grep to print all lines ending with `.`

```
$ grep '.$' File
A data file which contains a number of lines .
Most lines start with an upper case letter.
however some start with a lower case letter.
1 or 2 may start with a digit.
They should end with a full stop (period).
but not all do!
This line   has a combination of spaces and  tabs and ends with a space
3 lines are empty
You may want to verify the number of empty lines in this file.
There are some lines which only contain digits and white spaces, like the next 2.
1 2 3   4 5 6
7  8    9 0
```

Question is why are the lines

```
but not all do!
This line   has a combination of spaces and  tabs and ends with a space
3 lines are empty
```

and

```
1 2 3   4 5 6
7  8    9 0
```

added to the output even though they dont end with a `.`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.` is the regular expression for "any character". So you are grepping for lines ending with any character, which are not surprisingly all non-empty lines.

Escape the dot and you should be fine:

```
grep '\.$' File
```